# ggplot2: exact plot area to resize additional panels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often have multi-panel plots, where I only want the legend on the top panel.  The lower panels use the same colors and shapes.
Because the top panel includes a legend, the actual plotting area is reduced compared to the subsequent plots.  To make the plots line up on both sides, I typically use plot_grid() to insert a NULL plot to the right to take up the legend space.

Currently, I do this by hand/sight, which is always approximate.  Can I get ggplot2 to tell me exactly how long the axis plotting area is, so that I can add exactly the correct amount of empty space?

Stackoverflow tells me that this question has been asked several times, but I'm afraid those discussions have not shown me a clear strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Try `patchwork`.

Creating two plots, one with and one without a legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)
gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point(aes(color=cyl))
gg2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point(aes(color=cyl)) + scale_color_continuous(guide="none")
```

With `patchwork` we can stack them, and it handles space used by the legend(s).

```r
library(patchwork)
gg1 / gg2
```

[image: stacked ggplots, only one with a legend]

Comment: Thank you.  But sometimes I want to stack plots of different types, e.g. an evolutionary tree made with ggtree below conventional ggplot() + geom_point().  Is it likely  patchwork will know what to do?

Comment: Yes it generally does; I can't think of a situation with two ggplots where that didn't work. (#hubris) There are also manual approaches using for instance `ggplot2::ggplot_build()` to get into the guts of the plot, but `patchwork` in most cases can handle it much more simply.

Comment: BillPearson: I agree with JonSpring, but ultimately there's not much to be done in this answer. There are far too many disparate ggplot-based plots out there to try all of them, and your question included neither reproducible code (preferred) nor a clear description of what types of plots you are using, only the presence of a legend. The most direct answer to your question _here_ is unfortunately just: "try it". I don't have `ggtree` installed, but since it is merely an extension to `ggplot2`, it should work just fine. I'm interested, please report back!